# True or false, prove or find a counterexample. If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that $\{x_n^2\}$ converges, then $\{x_n\}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> True or false, prove or find a counterexample. If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that $\{x_n^2\}$ converges, then $\{x_n\}$ converges.

I know how to prove or show $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x_n^2\}$ are convergent using the epsilon/delta definition of convergence. But I don't quite get how to link the two things together. Please help me here. Thank you!

Comment: Counter example: $x_n = (-1)^n$.

Comment: Hints : $(-x)^2 = x^2$, so consider $1,-1,1,-1,...$. What is true ? Well, if $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, then indeed the statement is true.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false. Consider $x_n=(-1)^n$, then the sequence starting from $n=0$ alternates 1 and $-1$, so does not converge. But $\{x_n^2\}$ is a constant sequence of ones, so converges.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{x_n\}$ can change sign, then $(-)^n$ is a counterexample. If not,
then the statement is true, since $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ is a continue function.